# How do I upgrade my BQ Aquaris 4.5 to OTA-12?

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-touch, bq, aquaris

I am on OTA-11. A couple of days ago, I got a notification on my phone that a system update was available. However, when I go into Updates it says software is up to date. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, changing "Auto download" from "Wifi only" to "Always" fixed this. I was not connected to Wifi, but a setting called "Auto download" shouldn't affect a manual check for updates! Well - it's solved the problem.

Comment: It might be worth filing a bug [if someone else hasn't done so already] https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image

Answer (score 0):

Simple question first: Have you tried a reboot and started searching for the update again? Second thing I would say your phone allready downloaded the update and you should look in system directories for a file/folder with the size of the update (about 150MB I think). When the name name of it sounds like it, attach a .bak to it's name e.g.. Don't forget to make the filesystem readwrite. But you do this at your own risk. Don't do it if you're unsure. I don't know, whether this works, but it's a general method.

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty much the same issue when I upgraded last. The download got half way and failed. So when I went in to Updated.again there was no sign of OTA-12. So I rebooted and then went into Settings > About > Check for Updates and it was there to download. It went a bit slow but dis download in the end.